# Letter Evaluated As Number?

Tags: excel

In cell A1 is the letter "P". Can anyone tell me why in Excel if(A1>1,"True","False") evaluates as "True"? I don't understand as it is not a number.

Thomas.

Comment: According to Excel any text is greater than a number.

Comment: See [this page](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/12/10/excel-not-equal-to-greater-than-less-than/) or [this one](https://spreadsheeto.com/logical-operators/)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, Excel assumes numbers to be less than text.